# Merge two arrays together tagged by same id

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have a problem to combine two arrays together.
One array I've got the Questions and the Other are the answers.

`array_merge()` doesn't work because than I lost some keys + value's.
Also `array_intersect_key()` doesn't what I want, I hope someone can help me out.

Both array got key `[questionid]` that's the key I want to target on.

Array 1 (Answers);

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [questionid] => 28f68dc4-acc6-4ab7-956d-ca41abf3a4c2
            [answer] => Antwoord 89
            [extra] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [questionid] => 28f-28f68dc4-acc6-4ab7-956d-ca41abf3a4c20
            [answer] => Antwoord 20
            [extra] => Extra informatie 20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [questionid] => d8f-28f68dc4-acc6-4ab7-956d-ca41abf3a4c20
            [answer] => Antwoord 3
            [extra] => 
        )

)
```

And an array with the questions:

```
       (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [questionId] => 28f-28f68dc4-acc6-4ab7-956d-ca41abf3a4c20
                    [question] => 1. Question 1
                    [type] => typequestion/question-text-input
                )

        )
```

How the final array must look like is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [questionid] => 28f68dc4-acc6-4ab7-956d-ca41abf3a4c2
            [answer] => Antwoord 89
            [extra] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [questionid] => 28f-28f68dc4-acc6-4ab7-956d-ca41abf3a4c20
            [answer] => Antwoord 20
            [extra] => Extra informatie 20
            [question] => 1. Question 1
            [type] => typequestion/question-text-input
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [questionid] => d8f-28f68dc4-acc6-4ab7-956d-ca41abf3a4c20
            [answer] => Antwoord 3
            [extra] => 
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start to create an indexed array for the question to find them. Then, you could loop over the answers and add question data to current answer :

```
$indexedQuestions = [];
foreach ($questions as $question) {
    $id = $question['questionId'];
    $indexedQuestions[$id] = $question;
}

$combined = [];
foreach ($answers as $answer) {
    $id = $answer['questionid'];
    if (isset($indexedQuestions[$id])) {
        $combined[] = $answer + $indexedQuestions[$id];
    } else {
        $combined[] = $answer;
    }
}
```

See [example](https://3v4l.org/OahN4)

If you want to update the `$answers` array, you can use `&` to update `$answer` by reference.

```
foreach ($answers as &$answer) {
    $id = $answer['questionid'];
    if (isset($indexedQuestions[$id])) {
        $answer += $indexedQuestions[$id];
    }
}
```

See [example](https://3v4l.org/ZM3ZK)

Note that `questionid` is different that `questionId`, so you will get both key in combined arrays. You can use `unset()` to remove one of them, like in [this example](https://3v4l.org/CEKhk).

Comment: This one also works! Thanks for your fast reaction, think I gonna use this one because of getting an Combined array :)

Answer (score 1):

One way with simple `foreach()` loop and `array_search()`. Here array search will find on `$answers` array where the **questionId** exists and then it will put the **question** and **type** to the main `$questions` array.

**Note:** I see **questionId** with **I** in capital on answers array

```
foreach($questions as $key=>$value){
    $k = array_search($value['questionid'], array_column($answers, 'questionId'));
    if($k!==FALSE)){
        $questions[$key]['question'] = $answers[$k]['question'];
        $questions[$key]['type'] = $answers[$k]['type'];
    }
}
print_r($questions);
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/O4uDc

*Without modifying main array*,

```
$combineArray = [];
foreach($questions as $key=>$value){
    $combineArray[$key] = $value;
    $k = array_search($value['questionid'], array_column($answers, 'questionId'));
    if($k!==FALSE){
        $combineArray[$key]['question'] = $answers[$k]['question'];
        $combineArray[$key]['type'] = $answers[$k]['type'];
    }
}
print_r($combineArray);
```

**Working Demo:** https://3v4l.org/9vhla

Comment: This one works for me but is it possible to just make an new array like $combineArray instead of change questions.

Comment: @Gurdt late update but it should work without modifying the main array by using another array e.g $combinedArray as you said.

Comment: Added that working demo too. Hope it will help :)